# Specifiying benchmark and vintage when batch geocoding with geocoding.geo.census.gov

Tags: curl, geocode, census

I have looked at the REST API documentation (which only provides one example with a value of benchmark=9) and am not clear on how to make a batch request. In particular, the rest of the documentation does not mention a benchmark of "9," so I have no idea what this means. I have tried using the following benchmark and vintage from the documentation:

`curl --form addressFile="//filepath/input.csv" --form benchmark=Public_AR_ACS2013 --form vintage=Current_ACS2013 http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch --output geocoderresult.csv`

My problem is that I am getting 400 response with a "malformed syntax" error. Can anyone with experience using this API point out what part of my syntax is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this syntax and it worked to get both location (lon/lat) and census geographies:

```
curl --form addressFile=@tiger_50addresses_to_geocode.csv --form benchmark=Public_AR_Census2010 --form vintage=Census2010_Census2010 http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch
```

Comment: With this approach, results that are "Tie" return no results at all, whereas the single geocoder will return the multiple matches. Or is there another way to make this work for batches?